# How to minimize adobe air android app with as3?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have 2 buttons in my app ( my app published by flash cs6 for android ). one button for exit app and one button for minimize app (send app to background and show homepage).what is code for 2nd button in as3?

```
b1.addEventListener(MOUSE_UP,exitapp);
b2.addEventListener(MOUSE_UP,minimizeapp);
function exitapp(e:mouseevent)
{
nativeapplication.nativeapplication.exit();
}
function minimizeapp(e:mouseevent)
{
//...what code I should write here? 
}
```

Comment: You could try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624050/flex-run-air-application-in-background

Comment: thanks @LDMS,I tried that ,but that codes didnt minimize my app on my cell phone!

Comment: closing the window doesn't make it go away???  Do you have a multi-window app?

Comment: No, I have not multi-window app.and also that code you referred to, could not minimize the app, it didnt any thing!!I think the code is for flex, my project is in flash cs6

Comment: Flex/Flash doesn't matter (it's part of the AIR API), my guess is that window methods are ignored on mobile platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find this solution:

https://forums.adobe.com/message/5714697#5714697

Answer (score 0):

`NativeApplication` has a property called `activeWindow` which is an instance of `NativeWindow` which has a `minimize` method:

```
function minimizeapp(e:mouseevent)
{
    nativeapplication.activeWindow.minimize();
}
```

Comment: thanks @Marcela, but it didnt work on my android cellphone : NativeApplication.nativeApplication.activeWindow.minimize();

Comment: Sorry to hear that, it's possible that this is not supported on Android. If I find a better solution, I'll update my answer.